# Сохранение данных для нескольких объектов в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Искал везде, наверное не так искал)). Суть объясню на примере. Делаю журнал для универа по посещаемости. Есть список факультетов, кафедр, групп и студентов. Связка между ними реализовано. Проблема в том что я не могу сделать добавления посещаемости самих студентов.

т.е.
Выводиться список студентов определенного факультета, кафедры, группы. И потом по списку студентов выделять кто пришел а кто нет (чекбоксом например) и сохранять.

Можно любые примеры которые похожие на этот, главное понять сам суть. Заранее благодарю!!!

Comment: без кода вам не помогут

Comment: Доброе утро. Обратитесь к разделам документации по работе с несколькими моделями и табличному вводу. Вот для начала https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/input-tabular-input.md